# How to capitalize and italicize proper nouns with the same ending

Tags: capitalization, proper-nouns

Let's say there's an *English Language Questionnaire* and an *English Usage Questionnaire* (I want them to be italicized), and I want to refer to them together, by name. What should I use:

The *English Language* and *English Usage* questionnaires are...

The *English Language* and *English Usage Questionnaires* are...

The *English Language Questionnaire* and the *English Usage Questionnaire* are...

Or something else? If it makes a difference, note that by this point in my paper I have already described each of them separately, so the reader has seen both of these names before.

PS: Feel free to edit the title, as I had no idea how to ask this in one line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *English Language* and *English Usage* questionnaires are ... GOOD

The *English Language* and *English Usage Questionnaires* are ... BAD

The *English Language Questionnaire* and the *English Usage Questionnaire* are ... VERY GOOD

That's all.

Answer (score 0):

Besides Elberich's excellent suggestions, you could consider:

> The questionnaires on *English Language* and *English Usage* are...